Gecode Attribute Not Available In Phonenumbers Geocoder Library
I am working on PYCharm IDE application for getting address from latitude and longitude and I have also installed phonenumber and geocoder library to the project in PYCharm IDE but unfortunately geocode is not found in phonenumbers.geocoder.
Code
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers import geocoder
from phonenumbers import carrier
import folium
from opencage.geocoder import OpenCageGeocode
phone_number = input("Enter a phone number (with country code): ")
phoneNumber = phonenumbers.parse(phone_number)
#geocoder = OpenCageGeocode("503437953c574180b22457c6f764256c")
yourLocation=geocoder.description_for_number(phoneNumber,"en")
query = str(yourLocation)
results = geocoder.geocode(query)
lat = results[0]['geometry']['lat']
lng = results[0]['geometry']['lng']
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoapiExercises")
location = geolocator.reverse(lat,lng)
print(location.address)

Error is :
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\pythonProject123\Lib\nn.py", line 12, in <module>
results = geocoder.geocode(query)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'phonenumbers.geocoder' has no attribute 'geocode'

Question is:
HOW TO RESOLVE IT?

Are you using Anaconda?

@toyotaSupra  : No
